# Does Firebase Realtime Database delays in sending values to listeners

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase realtime database in my android app. And I have observed that if more than one phone is connected with database using value event listener, then the last connected phone receives data very late. Is it that firebase sends data to one by one client? then it will definitely cause delay.So how to cope with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. Actually I got answer on Slack Firebase community from a helpful user, and my doubts are clear now. He explained that this behavior is normal and delays maybe be scaled or constant. And He also said that data will be guaranteed to be received by all listeners though the node is updated during delay period. And data is not lost but delay is certain.

I hope this may help somebody who faced same issue like me.

Answer (score 2):

No firebase database is realtime and all changes are reflected immediately all devices connected to a database gets data simultaneously. Check your network connectivity of device

Comment: I have checked the connectivity and found ok. But I have connected 3 phones with database using valueeventlistener but the delay has increased device to device. The first phone connected was receiving data fast but the second phone received data with delay and the third phone got data with more delay than second one. By the way all phones were listening to common node.